# we need some on automated email on sharepoint Expected is

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, automation

we need some on automated email on sharepoint  Expected is to setup a sharepoint (Single page sharepoint) and setup automated emails to a group from it triggered on particular dates  Can you help assign an expert for it

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send email to SharePoint Group on schedule. The easiest approach will be using PowerAutomate (MS flow).

Here is an example about how to do it:
https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2018/03/using-flow-to-send-email-reminder-from-sharepoint-data/